# weird ActiveRecord time zone behavior in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, timezone

I'm in Brazil, which is -3 hours from UTC.
I have NOT done any configuration for time zones in Rails, and my console is behaving weird, here is the example:

```
    1.9.3p194 :099 >   FreeTime.first.starts_at
     => 2000-01-01 11:15:26 UTC 
    1.9.3p194 :100 > FreeTime.first.starts_at.localtime
     => 2000-01-01 09:15:26 -0200 
    1.9.3p194 :101 > FreeTime.first.starts_at.localtime.zone
     => "BRST" 
    1.9.3p194 :102 > Time.now
     => 2013-02-25 10:24:51 -0300 
    1.9.3p194 :103 > Time.now.zone
     => "BRT" 
    1.9.3p194 :104 > Time.zone
     => (GMT+00:00) UTC
```

As you can see, the problem is that Rails Time class figures out correctly my localzone (from my system clock), but ActiveRecord somehow gets it wrong. I would like to know why ActiveRecord figures out wrongly that my timezone is BRST (the right is BRT), even though I haven't done any configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not getting it wrong at all. It realizes you're in the Brazil time zone, and at 2000-01-01 11:15:26 UTC, the Brazil time zone was in BRST, which is UTC-2.

In [the year 2000](http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/timezone.html?n=45&syear=2000), the BRST -> BRT transition was on February 26th.

You need to understand that your time zone isn't really "BRT" or "BRST" - it's a combination of the two, including the transitions between them. So for example I'm in the UK. We're currently on GMT, we'll be transitioning to BST in the summer - so the correct output for a time value in the summer would be BST, at UTC+1.

Comment: Great answer! I'm starting to realize that the best way to have a Time field on database is having and Integer for Hour, and an Integer for Minutes. Since I'm in Brasil, every time I store a Time, it will be in 2000-01-01, and consequently in wrong time zone.

Comment: @user1261084: That's rarely the best way to start times, to be honest. In *most* cases, storing the values as UTC is the write approach - best there are cases where storing the local date/time along with the time zone is better.

Comment: If I have an appointment every Tuesday at 15:00, on summertime it will continue to be at 15:00. But if I store it on database as "15:00:00 -0300", on summertime it will give me back that the appointment is on "16:00:00 -0200". Very confusing...Time is time, for a lots of cases it doesn't relies on Zones. DateTime relies on zones. I don't get why Rails insists in recording the date in Time database attributes. It should exist a better approach to avoid this confusion. Right now I store Time as "11:00:00 -0300", and it gives me back "11:00:00 -0200": https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5030404

Comment: @user1261084: Yes, repeated events are one good example of where storing the local time and time zone information is appropriate. It wasn't really clear that you were *just* trying to store a time of day value (rather than date and time).

Comment: What about the gist, don't you think that it's a weird behavior recording "12:01:36 -0300" and retrieving "12:01:36 -0200". I know this is due to how activerecord deals with Time fields (recording the date). My point is that it isn't the best approach. The best approach would be only storing time and zone (like: "12:01:36 -0300"), not the date. Don't you think? Thanks for all the great answers!